# Get element attribute when using after()

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i use this to get the source of the image

```
function pinterest_it() {
    $("#page_wrapper img").after("<p>" + this.src + "</p>");
}
```

I'm guessing in this source code "this" is being used incorrectly. Can anyone tell me what i can use to get the images src?

Comment: [jQuery Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/after/) is great ! Have a look to the 2nd "after" method signature .. I sure you can get the solution `;)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`.after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/) accepts a function that should return an HTML string, DOM element or jQuery object to be appended after the elements in the selected set.

In that function, `this` is the current DOM element in the set, which in your case is the `img`.

```
$("#page_wrapper img").after(function(){
  return "<p>" + this.src + "</p>"
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("#page_wrapper img").after(function(){
    return "<p>" + $(this).attr("src") + "</p>"
  });
```